# awk sum up multiple files show lines which does not appear on both sets of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, awk

I have been using awk to sum up multiple files, this is used to sum up the summary of server log parsing values, it really does speed up the final overall count but I have hit a minor problem and the typical examples I have hit on the web have not helped.

Here is the example:

```
cat file1
aa 1
bb 2
cc 3
ee 4

cat file2
aa 1
bb 2
cc 3
dd 4

cat file3
aa 1
bb 2
cc 3
ff 4
```

And the script:

```
cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

files="file1 file2 file3"

i=0;
oldname="";
for names in $(echo $files); do
        ((i++));
        if [ $i == 1 ]; then
                oldname=$names
                #echo "-- $i $names"
                shift;
        else
               oldname1=$names.$$
        awk  'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$1] != "") nn=0; nn=($2+_[$1]); print $1" "nn }' $names $oldname> $oldname1
        if [ $i -gt 2 ]; then
            rm $oldname;
        fi
                oldname=$oldname1

    fi
done
echo "------------------------------ $i"
cat $oldname
```

When I run this, the identical columns are added up but those that appear only in one of the files does not

```
./test.sh 
------------------------------ 3
aa 3
bb 6
cc 9
ee 4
```

ff dd does not appear in the list, from what I have seen its within the NR==FR

I have come across this:

http://dbaspot.com/shell/246751-awk-comparing-two-files-problem.html

```
you want all the lines in file1 that are not in file2,
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$0]; next } !($0 in a)' file2 file1

If you want only uniq lines in file1 that are not in file2,
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$0]; next } !($0 in a) { print; a[$0] }'
file2
file1
```

but this only complicates current issue further when attempted since lots of other fields get duplicated

**After posting question - updates to the content ... and tests....**

I wanted to stick with awk since it does appear to be a much shorter way of achieving result there is a problem still..

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (k in a) print k,a[k]}'  file1 file2 file3
aa 3
bb 6
cc 9
ee 4
ff 4
gg 4
RESULT_SET_4 0
RESULT_SET_3 0
RESULT_SET_2 0
RESULT_SET_1 0
$ cat file1 
RESULT_SET_1
aa 1
RESULT_SET_2
bb 2
RESULT_SET_3
cc 3
RESULT_SET_4
ff 4
$ cat file2
RESULT_SET_1
aa 1
RESULT_SET_2
bb 2
RESULT_SET_3
cc 3
RESULT_SET_4
ee 4
```

The file content is not left as it was originally i.e. the results are not under the headings, my original method did keep it all intact

**Updated expected output - headings in correct context**

```
cat file1 
RESULT_SET_1
aa 1
RESULT_SET_2
bb 2
RESULT_SET_3
cc 3
RESULT_SET_4
ff 4



cat file2 
RESULT_SET_1
aa 1
RESULT_SET_2
bb 2
RESULT_SET_3
cc 3
RESULT_SET_4
ee 4


cat file3
RESULT_SET_1
aa 1
RESULT_SET_2
bb 2
RESULT_SET_3
cc 3
RESULT_SET_4
gg 4
test.sh awk line to produce above is :

awk -v i=$i 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if (_[$1] != "") { if  ($2 ~ /[0-9]/)   { nn=($2+_[$1]); print $1" "nn; } else { print;} }else { print; } }' $names $oldname> $oldname1

./test.sh 
------------------------------ 3
RESULT_SET_1
aa 3
RESULT_SET_2
bb 6
RESULT_SET_3
cc 9
RESULT_SET_4
ff 4
```

works but destroys required formatting

```
  awk '($2 != "")  {a[$1]+=$2};  ($2 == "") {  a[$1]=$2 } END {for (k in a) print k,a[k]} '  file1 file2 file3
    aa 3
    bb 6
    cc 9
    ee 4
    ff 4
    gg 4
    RESULT_SET_4 
    RESULT_SET_3 
    RESULT_SET_2 
    RESULT_SET_1
```

Comment: What are "the headings"?  I don't see anything like that in the example data you first posted.  This makes it a different question.  If you change the question this significantly AFTER it has been answered, you probably shouldn't expect folks to answer it a second time.

Comment: yep sorry :) my bad, the reports do have headings then field values should i repost a new question?

Comment: What is the expected output now?

Comment: updated the question with expected output, basically each servers output will have headings for each segment followed by field and its values... kind of like the last updated content of file1 file2 and the expected result is produced by original script - with the obvious issue still there - the process below does work but the order is lost and headings appear in incorrect format

Comment: I think this will be very useful for others so long as they think about logs differently in the first instance.. so I have put it as a project here https://github.com/vahidhedayati/summarise-server-logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (k in a) print k,a[k]}' file1 file2 file3 | sort
aa 3
bb 6
cc 9
dd 4
ee 4
ff 4
```

**Edit:**

It's a bit of a hack but it does the job:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR&&!/RESULT/{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a){a[$1]+=$2}END{for (k in a) print k,a[k]}' file1 file2 file3 | sort | awk '$1="RESULTS_SET_"NR"\n"$1'
RESULTS_SET_1
aa 3
RESULTS_SET_2
bb 6
RESULTS_SET_3
cc 9
RESULTS_SET_4
ff 4
```

Comment: **+1**  That's almost exactly how I'd do it.  (I might have chosen different single-letter variable and array names. ;] )

Comment: there is still an issue in the case of rows that are not supposed to be added, I have updated the original post

Comment: Thanks Sudo, this works fine so long as the content within each heading is 1 field, if there are multiple fields values under a heading it will only show the first :(

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `awk`, as sudo_O suggested, but you can also do it in pure bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

# We'll use an associative array, where the indexes are strings.
declare -A a

# Our list of files, in an array (not associative)
files=(file1 file2 file3)

# Walk through array of files...
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  # And for each file, increment the array index with the value.
  while read index value; do
    ((a[$index]+=$value))
  done < "$file"
done 

# Walk through array. ${!...} returns a list of indexes.
for i in ${!a[@]}; do
  echo "$i ${a[$i]}"
done
```

And the result:

```
$ ./doit
dd 4
aa 3
ee 4
bb 6
ff 4
cc 9
```

And if you want the output sorted ... you can pipe it through `sort`. :)

Comment: Yes, of course.  The checkmark is in the right place.  I included this because the question is also tagged *bash*, and bash scripting is fun.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk File1 File2 File3
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
sub(/RESULT_SET_/,"") {

    i = $1
    next
}

{
    a[i][$1]+=$2
}

END {
    for (j=1;j<=length(a);j++) {

        print "RESULT_SET_" j

        for (k in a[j]) {
            print k, a[j][k]
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
RESULT_SET_1
aa 3
RESULT_SET_2
bb 6
RESULT_SET_3
cc 9
RESULT_SET_4
ee 4
ff 4
gg 4
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'sub(/RESULT_SET_/,"") { i = $1; next } { a[i][$1]+=$2 } END { for (j=1;j<=length(a);j++) { print "RESULT_SET_" j; for (k in a[j]) print k, a[j][k] } }' File1 File2 File3
```

Comment: is this running on Linux ? awk 'sub(/RESULT_SET_/,"") { i = $1; next } { a[i][$1]+=$2 } END { for (j=1;j<=length(a);j++) { print "RESULT_SET_" j; for (k in a[j]) print k, a[j][k] } }' file1 file2 file3
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near [
awk: line 1: illegal reference to array a
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near [

Comment: ./script.awk file1 file2 
./script.awk: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `/RESULT_SET_/,""'
./script.awk: line 1: `sub(/RESULT_SET_/,"") {'

Comment: it has to be gawk 4 + initial gawk 3.XX was not working - cool

Comment: @vahid: Yes, I would prefer to see a solution to your problem using `GNU awk` (and I'm assuming you've got the latest version of it installed). The solution itself can be made a lot simpler using a multidimensional array - and it would be more maintainable too. If you're happy with it, don't forget to accept it. If not, please let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Steve I was testing this earlier and although on a simpler example all seemed well, on my real results it did not work out too well, the order of the items within each sub heading had changed, I had to also define headings as the RESULT_SET_1 _2 and so forth for it to work

Comment: @vahid: I see what you mean. I relied too heavily on the heading names being consistent. I'll see if I can update my answer. I may be a while, I've got a couple of other things to fix up first.

Comment: @vahid: Just a question - how then do you define what a header line is? If possible would you be able to send me your real data? Use pastebin, dropbox etc.

Comment: will do I may create a new question - since it will be a very useful script - something that takes any output from any server results (regardless of what headings data falls under etc)

Comment: I also found the summing up had not worked out as expected in this method, I compared the values from previous runs and the values were really low using this method... I have provided a sample version of the log file on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891181/bash-awk-script-to-sum-up-server-reports-that-are-quite-similar-but-may-have-uni

Answer (score 0):

fixed using this
Basically it goes through each file, if the entry exists on the other side, it will add the entry to approximate line number with a 0 value so that it can sum up the content - been testing this on my current output and seems to be working real well

```
#!/bin/bash

 files="file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8"
RAND="$$"
i=0;
oldname="";
for names in $(echo $files); do
        ((i++));
        if [ $i == 1 ]; then
                oldname=$names
                shift;
        else
               oldname1=$names.$RAND
        for entries in $(awk -v i=$i 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if (_[$1] == "") { if  ($2 ~ /[0-9]/)   { nn=0; nn=(_[$1]+=$2);  print FNR"-"$1"%0"} else { } } else { } }' $oldname $names); do
                line=$(echo ${entries%%-*})
                content=$(echo ${entries#*-})
                content=$(echo $content|tr "%" " ")

edit=$(ed -s $oldname  << EOF
$line
a
$content
.
w
q
EOF 
)

$edit  >/dev/null 2>&1

done

                awk -v i=$i 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if (_[$1] != "") { if  ($2 ~ /[0-9]/)   { nn=0; nn=($2+_[$1]); print $1" "nn; } else { print $1;} }else { print; } }' $names $oldname> $oldname1
        oldname=$oldname1
    fi
done

cat $oldname
#rm file?.*
```