# Check if line exists in a file

Tags: android, xml, bash, shell, scripting

The problem is that my app tries to add a line to an existing xml file in `/system/csc`.

I need a function to check if inside the file there is X line and if it is in there the line shouldn't be added also it has to put the line before another line that is present in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the line already exist with `grep` and use `sed` to insert it if not:

```
grep -Fxq "foobar line" file || sed -i '/^context line$/i foobar line' file
```

This will insert the line `foobar line` before the line `context line` if `foobar line` isn't already found in the file.

Alternately you could do it all with `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^foobar line$/d;/^context line$/i foobar line' file
```

Comment: The second version is a little risky.  That will remove all occurrences of the line and insert a new one before the context line.  Although it seems likely that the user expects the line to exist only once and to already be before the context line, that requirement is not explicit.

Comment: @WilliamPursell probably a benefit in this instance but definitely worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
grep -F "$yourLine" file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

[awk sum up multiple files show lines which does not appear on both sets of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876624/awk-sum-up-multiple-files-show-lines-which-does-not-appear-on-both-sets-of-files)
check my answer on this page (the last answer to my own question) I am using ed and after finding the line that the entry needs to be added to I use typical vi commands to add the entry after the line number.

You can use the same script after doing a grep for string in your file if not

```
grep pattern $file > /dev/null
if  [ $? = 0 ]; then
 echo "found"
else
run_ed_function
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if string equals  ENTIRE LINE

```
FILE="./myfile"
STRING="myString"


if grep -x ^$STRING.$ $FILE; then
  echo 'Found'
else
  echo 'Not Found'
fi
```

In that case, the code would match 'myString' but not 'Hello myString'